# Where do you put a firewall in the network?

Tags: networking, firewall, opnsense

I have installed opnsense on a pc to use as my business firewall where do I put this in my network

Do I put it just off of a port on my switch or do I need a 2 port ethernet card and plug the internet into one and my router into the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A firewall is only useful if connections actually go *through* it. It'll do nothing at all if it just dangles off a single switch – it cannot somehow "attract" traffic<sup>1</sup>, all your client devices will just continue to directly talk to the router/gateway.

To work properly, the firewall needs to have separate connections for "outside" and "inside", i.e. it needs to sit between the Internet and the LAN. This *usually* means two Ethernet ports – one from your ISP connection, one to your LAN switch.

But it is possible to use two VLANs over a single Ethernet port (also known as "on a stick" configuration), although your switch must also support VLAN tagging and it won't necessarily provide as good performance as separate physical ports would.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Except by using ARP spoofing, and yes, I've *heard of* one or two "plug and play" firewall products which do exactly that, but... I would *not* want to use a security product that is literally performing an attack against the network.)

Comment: Thanks but do I just add another network card to by pc and then plug that into by switch in put??? will opnsence work like that or is will that not work??

Comment: Hi I ended up getting it to work